# Why is my ASP.NET website not found by Visual Studio on a different computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I was working on a WCF service application in Visual Studio 2012 on my laptop while I was on the train. I'd much rather do work on my desktop so naturally, I zipped up the project files and transferred it over. The project contains the WCF service and an ASP.NET Web Forms Site. I've specified "Use Visual Studio Development Server" and assigned a static port to my project. Everything works on my laptop but for whatever reason, I get the following error when Visual Studio 2012 on my desktop tries to open my solution (specifically the ASP.NET Website Project).

```
http://localhost:5137 : error  : Error opening web http://localhost:5137. The Web site 'http://localhost:5137' could not be found.
```

I'm not entirely sure what's going on here. The WCF service seems to be working just fine, but not the ASP.NET Website. What is the meaning of this error and how do I fix it? Also, how would I go about avoiding this in later projects? I'm sure not being able to move my work to other places is probably a problem.

I suspect this has something to do with whatever random port number "5137" was generated for the ASP.NET Website but I don't really know.

Thanks,

-Theo

Comment: What happens when you open Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: I have run VS as administrator, it still gets the same error.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the solution to open in VS and build again? may be you after compiling the code running it on your desktop machine via F5 or ctrl + F5 will run again the website.

I do face these random port number problems and what I do is restart :) 
hope this help